# How two cosets are same in this example

Tags: group-theory

I was reading about cosets from example 298 in this [pdf](http://math.kennesaw.edu/%7Eplaval/math4361/cosets.pdf).

I repeat the problem here:

> Let $G = \{e, a, a^2, a^3\} = <a>$ where $|a| = 4$.
>
> Let $H = \{e,a^2\} = < a^2 >$
>
> Then $Ha = {a,a^3}$
>
> $Ha^2 = \{a^2,a^4\} = \{e,a^2\} = H$

I didnt get how $\{a^2,a^4 \} = \{e,a^2\}$ above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of $a$ is $4$ (which is what $|a| = 4$ means), then that means $a^4 = e$, the identity element.

Comment: ok I think I miss some theory here, a bit of explaination / link?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_%28group_theory%29  and http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/order.pdf

Comment: ok am a bit new to group theory, so just want to confirm what I understood: both $\{a^2,a^4\}$ and $\{e,a^2\}$ have order 2 i.e. generated by $a^2$, hence we write $\{a^2,a^4\} = \{e,a^2\}$ and both are denoted as <$a^2$> as in generated by $a^2$